# Why does Carol not get rid of the Kree symbol on her suit when she changes its colours?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019, captain-marvel

After Carol finds out the truth about her past and how Yon-Rogg lied to her, she claims she can no longer wear the Kree colours (dark green) and allows Monica to choose the new colour scheme of her suit. But why does she not make any attempt to get rid of the Kree star symbol on the chest of her suit? We see this symbol in various places on Hala so it's clearly a national/global symbol of the Kree race so surely it would make more sense to change it rather than the colour of her suit?

The emblem may provide some kind of function in the suit which may prevent her from removing/changing it, but most of the functionality of the suit seems to come from the bracer on her wrist. Also, Carol seems to have enough engineering know-how (she's able to upgrade Fury's pager to be able to call her across the galaxy) that she should be able to tinker with the emblem enough to at least change the exterior look of it.

Comment: Changing the desktop on my computer is a lot easier than ripping off the logo on the monitor

Comment: Comparing the situation to soccer: If you change teams, you get a new tricot with another color, but the outfit itself looks similar after all. Also if I remember correctly, there is a saying about "changing color" if you swap teams

Comment: Note that the new scheme was patterned after Monica's USAF T-shirt, which also has a star; it's not the same shape (5 points rather than 8) but maybe Monica thought it was closer than no star at all.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Well Carol makes the final adjustments but that's a good point

Comment: This question does not bother me as much as how Monica knew how to use that alien wrist computer to get exactly the colors she wanted.

Comment: @kikirex I got the impression she was just pressing stuff rather than knowing how to use it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Just pressing stuff could have ended with something like: "hey, I can't do anything good, you'll be neon purple then."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although all the stars look similar, they're different for each member of the Kree Starforce team. So they are kind of like personal heraldry for each "warrior hero".

[This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/b2ksmb/starforce_symbols_in_captain_marvel/) illustrates the differences.

[image: The Kree Starforce's different star symbols]

So she wouldn't change her personal insignia as it's unique to her. I guess it was just lucky she has the coolest, most-iconic design.

Comment: This was an excellent find. For an update this is backed up in _Marvel's Captain Marvel: The Art Of The Movie_ where Sanja Milkovic Hays _"But each costume is unique because they are a specialized force, and each has his or her own weapons. Each costume has a different star."_ See my answer for the full quote.

Answer (score 29):

I myself wondered about this for a while and have come up with a few possible reasons.

#### The suit was based on Monica's t-shirt

The suit was based on Monica's t-shirt which was red, blue and had a star on it. As such it seems likely that Carol kept the star as a reference to this as well as the other reasons.

[image: Close up of Monica wearing the t-shirt]
<sub>*Click to enlarge and see the full image.*</sub>

#### She does "alter" it... sort of

Perhaps quite importantly, she does alter the colours of the suit around the logo to make it look like the logo extends onto the suit further than before hand. See the gold strips to the side of it on the new look compared to the old:

[image: Carol's red and blue colour suit]
<sub>*Click to enlarge.*</sub>

[image: Vers' green colour suit]
<sub>*Click to enlarge.*</sub>

#### The Starforce uniforms are personalised

We can see in the above image that each member of Starforce has a slightly different uniform. As mentioned in [this excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/208044/58193) the stars on each person's chest are also tailored. This was indeed a conscious design because each member is unique and has their own weapons as Sanja Milkovic Hays states below in *Marvel's Captain Marvel: The Art Of The Movie*.

> The Starforce uniforms are similar in design and color scheme, but each has unique detailing. "They were designed on the Captain Marvel costume," Costume Designer Sanja Milkovic Hays says. "Her costume is almost the same. It's just a different color, black and teal, and then everybody else's are similar. But each costume is unique because they are a specialized force, and each has his or her own weapons. Each costume has a different star. Each has slightly different lines, different shoulders, different weapons. I think for all of us, the first time we saw Starforce, it was like, 'Oh my God. This really works.' It was just really amazing."
>
> [image: Page from the book quoted above and also showing concept art for Starforce]

#### Was it possible?

It's also worth pointing out that as mentioned in [Stark07's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/207689/58193) the suit itself probably didn't have the in built functionality to be able to make physical changes, it only appears to be able to change the colour of the suit. Therefore, she would probably have had to make the modifcations by hand rather than through any built in process.

However, there are two things that could be evidence against this theory. The first is that her helmet comes out of the suit so maybe it can make modifications on the fly. Of course this is easily explained by this being an in built function though.

The second and perhaps more important thing though is that we do see her change the appearance albeit ever so slightly of the suit as mentioned below. She adds gold bands at the side of the star which do look slightly different to the bands that were there previously.

#### Was there time to?

The mission wasn't exactly time critical but it did need to be done quickly. Carol didn't exactly have the time to play around with such an unimportant part of her suit, changing the colours immediately sends the signal that she's changed. Further changing the symbol wouldn't have affected that much.

If I'm remembering correctly when she actually decides to change the colours she's just about to leave so there probably wasn't time to take the suit off and remove the logo.

#### Was it needed?

As mentioned above changing the colour of the suit sends a strong signal that she's changed alliances and so changing the symbol wasn't actually necessary.

Comment: That's not just a colour change, those bands are entirely new!

Comment: @Baldrickk There were originally bands there but on closer inspection they do appear to be slightly different aye.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot now I want a pic of the post credits suit to compare

Comment: https://www.elitedaily.com/p/heres-what-captain-marvels-post-credits-scenes-set-up-for-avengers-endgame-16826158 bands are completely different, though it's still an 8-pointed star

Comment: And more googling reveals a different suit in the post credits of Ant man and the Wasp (not seen - yet) and yet another design...  so there are certainly a number of changes that the suit has gone through, but not all shown in this film

Comment: @Baldrickk Well after the events of Captain Marvel and in Endgame the suit might not even be the same one considering 20 or so years have passed.

Comment: Yeah, the post credit scene in Cpt Marvel was interesting in terms of how she would change it over time.  It's odd that it's a different suit in AM&TW.  I assume it'll just be the post credits sit in endgame.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the suit modification function could modify only basic appearance, such as colours, and couldn't really alter the physical structure of the suit.

We see her playing around with various colour combinations, but never does the suit change the basic structure.

Think of it like having LCD panels everywhere on the suit. You can't change the shape, but you can tune the colour.

Comment: This is a good point and something I meant to include in my answer. I will note though that this doesn't stop her from making alterations outside of the suit's functions.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this, too, but I assumed the in-universe explanation is the star was functional, and not just decorative... that it housed some of the tech needed to make the rest of the suit or arm-piece work, and therefore was not so simple a thing to remove.